# MySQL: how to pivot?

Tags: mysql

Say I have the following tables:

```
TABLE: foo
- foo_id (PK)
- foo_value

Table: bar
- bar_id (PK)
- foo_id (FK)
- var_value
```

There is a one to many relationship between `foo` and `bar`. How do I query this so that I get a result like this:

```
1, `foo`.`value`, `bar`.`value1`
2, `foo`.`value`, `bar`.`value1`, `bar`.`value2`
3, `foo`.`value`, `bar`.`value1`, `bar`.`value2`, `bar`.`value3`
4, `foo`.`value`, `bar`.`value1`, `bar`.`value2`, `bar`.`value3` .... and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't.

A longer answer is that you can do this:

```
 SELECT foo.foo_id, foo_value, GROUP_CONCAT(var_value ORDER BY bar_id)
 FROM foo, bar
 WHERE bar.foo_id=bar.foo_id
 GROUP BY foo.foo_id, foo_value
```

However your example schema doesn't make a lot of sense. Consider instead where bar always has an *indentifiable* core set of, say 4 records, for each foo record, then bar would look something like:

- bar_id
- foo_id
- bar_type
- bar_value

Then you can do this:

```
SELECT foo_id, foo_value, 
(SELECT b1.var_value
 FROM bar b1
 WHERE b1.type=1),
(SELECT b2.var_value
 FROM bar b2
 WHERE b1.type=2),
(SELECT b3.var_value
 FROM bar b3
 WHERE b1.type=3),
(SELECT b4.var_value
 FROM bar b4
 WHERE b4.type=4)
FROM foo
```